# Unable to see biztalk project template in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have installed BizTalk 2013 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate is also installed on the same machine.

I cannot see BizTalk Project template while creating a new project in Visual Studio.
When I ran the BizTalk setup again, Developer Tools box was not selected. When I select the box it gives following message

```
Features you selected requires the following components to be installed: 
WCF HTTP ACTIVATION 4.5, IIS ASP NET 4.5
```

When I check in the Server Manager, both of the above are already installed.

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you registered ASP.NET 4.5 on the machine?

Try running this command:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

You can read more about the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe) here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

The easiest way to do this would be to run the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
Also make sure to run as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

To restore the default project templates
In the command prompt, navigate to the location of devenv.exe. This file is located in \Common7\IDE.
Type "devenv /installvstemplates" and press Enter.
NoteNote:
If you are using an Express Edition of Visual Studio, type "Express /installvstemplates" where  is either VB, VJS, or VCS for Visual Basic, Visual J#, and Visual C#, respectively.
If this procedure does not restore the default templates, reinstall Visual Studio.

U can follow this link also:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f1cd2e14-1d7e-4b84-8bc2-871d67e2a942/devenvexe-installvstemplates-not-install-propertly